# looking for an efficient way to split columns in a text in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have pandas dataframe and want to split the `text` column in such a way that each row has just two words. when splitting, I need to maintain the order so that I can combine them together based on `line`. Is there efficient way to do this. I can do list comprehension but was looking at more efficient way. Thanks

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[22,23,44], 'col2': ['rr','gg','xx'], 'text': ['this is a sample text', 'this is another one','third example is a longer text']})
```

[image]

Comment: post the input `df` generation code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), and [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
out = (df.assign(text=df['text'].str.findall(r'(\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)'))
         .explode('text')
         .assign(line=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
       )
```

Regexes variant to handle any number of words:

```
N=2
out = (df.assign(text=df['text'].str.findall(fr'((?:\S+\s+){{,{N-1}}}(?:\S+))\s*'))
         .explode('text')
         .assign(line=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
       )
```

Alternative with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)' `batched` recipe:

```
from itertools import islice

def batched(iterable, n):
    "Batch data into tuples of length n. The last batch may be shorter."
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield batch

N = 2
out = (df.assign(text=df['text'].map(lambda x: list(map(' '.join, batched(x.split(), N)))))
         .explode('text')
         .assign(line=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
       )
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2           text  line
0    22   rr        this is     0
0    22   rr       a sample     1
0    22   rr           text     2
1    23   gg        this is     0
1    23   gg    another one     1
2    44   xx  third example     0
2    44   xx           is a     1
2    44   xx    longer text     2
```

Example output with `N=4`:

```
   col1 col2                 text  line
0    22   rr     this is a sample     0
0    22   rr                 text     1
1    23   gg  this is another one     0
2    44   xx   third example is a     0
2    44   xx          longer text     1
```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt using [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) :

```
chunks = (
    df.pop("text").str.extractall(r"(\S+)\s?(\S+)?")
        .fillna("").agg(" ".join, axis=1).str.strip()
)

out = df.join(chunks.rename_axis(["", "line"]).reset_index(level=-1, name="text"))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   col1 col2  line           text
0    22   rr     0        this is
0    22   rr     1       a sample
0    22   rr     2           text
1    23   gg     0        this is
1    23   gg     1    another one
2    44   xx     0  third example
2    44   xx     1           is a
2    44   xx     2    longer text
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using `str.split()` on the text and rejoining it with `str.join()`
Here's a quick example I cooked up:

```
#df==input
output=pd.DataFrame(data=[],columns=list(df.columns)+['line'])
for row in range(len(df)):
    textToSplit=df.iat[row,2]
    wordsPerRow=2
    lineCount=0
    #iterate through list ['word1 word2','word3 word4'...etc]
    for val in [' '.join(textToSplit.split(' ')[i:i+wordsPerRow]) for i in range(0, textToSplit.count(' ')+1, wordsPerRow)]:
        #add the row to the output, replacing the requested text and adding the line number
        output.loc[len(output)]=[val if i==textToSplit else i for i in list(df.loc[row])]+[lineCount]
        lineCount+=1
```

Using your dataframe as input, I got this output:

```
  col1    col2      text            line
0   22      rr      this is         0
1   22      rr      a sample        1
2   22      rr      text            2
3   23      gg      this is         0
4   23      gg      another one     1
5   44      xx      third example   0
6   44      xx      is a            1
7   44      xx      longer text     2
```